# jQuery imgelens plugin - Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imageLens'

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am working on a eCommerce project at work which has two sides to it both different websites
The starting point for them both are the same the have all the same jQuery files linked and are identical if in view source.

On one site jQuery imgelens plugin works fine you scroll of the image and it zooms in
On the other site i get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'imageLens'

which refers to this peace of code

```
jQuery(function () {
    jQuery("#img_product_1").imageLens({
        lensSize: 200,
        borderSize: 1,
        borderColor: '#666666',
        imageSrc:"http://koolkiddz.co.uk/images/main/11456/1.gif?state=0.1646016"
    });
});
```

Both sites call imageLens the same way with the same attributes and both can see the main jQuery file and the imageLens file.

Can someone come up with a possible reason or solution for why this is happen

http://koolkiddz.co.uk/item.asp?optProduct=172&txtItem=11456 here is the site with the error

http://wholesale.koolkiddz.co.uk/item.asp?optProduct=170&txtItem=11412 Here is the site without the error

There are little differences with the code but as you will see all the jquery and javascript are called the same

Comment: your ImageLens plugin not loaded.. check whether you are geting 404 erros in the page ?? use Fiddler /chrome developer tools (network tab)

Comment: Are you loading jQuery **before** the plugin?

Comment: and your script order should be like this.. 
1st Jquery library, 2nd script would be ImageLens plugin

Comment: I reference jquery before i call the plugin. The page can see the jquery file and the plugin file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I look into your jquery.imageLens.js file I see $.fn.imageLens1
Try to download the jquery plugin again at

http://www.dailycoding.com/Uploads/2011/03/imageLens/jquery.imageLens.js

and overwrite the existing one, or just try to remove the 1 after $.fn.imageLens

Comment: This solution worked at some point the file must of been edited.

Answer (score 0):

there is missing html tag "<"html">" in the page with error fix it and check.